# Type hinting in function argument (magic __call) throw exception

Tags: php, string, casting

This one really messes with my head:

Whenever I try to typecast a var passed to a function of type 'string', like this:

```
public function __call( string $name , array $args ) {
    ...
}
```

I get the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to [ClassName]::__call() must
>   be an instance of string, string given in [php_file_name] on line
>   [line_number]

Huh? "Must be an instance of string, string given"? Did I not pass a string?  I seriously don't understand this error message.

Now my solution has always been something like:

```
public function __call( $name , array $args ) {
    if (!is_string($name)) { throw new Exception('$name must be a string');
}
```

However, my question, is there a way to actually typecast it in the method definition rather than inside the method itself?

Comment: Correction, this is not type casting, but type hinting

Comment: Aareon - Nope, there is no way to force a cast here. Type hinting *expects* a string, that's how it works. It doesn't convert them. Why are you in the situation that you're passing a non-string in the first place?

Comment: Show us the code you use to *call* `__call()`. Particularly the variable passed.

Comment: @ajreal ahh yes, thats what I meant, type hinting, type casting is definining the variable to be 'evaluated as', I know :) Sorry my bad

Comment: @Aareon In the above example, that would actually not happen (magic method), however it was more just a general question about facing this error, the method could have been : doAnything(string $name, array $value) for all intense purposes

Comment: @JasonMcCreary would be something like $myClass->doSomething("fun"); where the method does not exist in the class of course.  The point was not so much the name of the method, rather the issue with 'Type Hinting' (as I have found can not be done except in the case of Objects and array.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In php you can force functions parameters to be either an array or an object (type hinting). So your action is only accepting "string" objects for the first argument, not variables of type string.

> Type Hints can only be of the object and array (since PHP 5.1) type. Traditional type hinting with int and string isn't supported.

More info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

And to answer your question: Normally, you can't!

Comment: Ahh yes: "Type Hints can only be of the object and array (since PHP 5.1) type. Traditional type hinting with int and string isn't supported." (on that documentation page).  Guess that is why I have always did the checking within the method itself.  I guess RTFM applies here :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't support scalar type-hinting. Only for objects and arrays. Someone at the PHP-comments has written a way to use scalar type-hinting. Because this error is of the type `catchable fatal error`. You can define your own error handler which lets you continue from this error in certain conditions.

http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.typehinting.php#83442

However, it's quite slow and I don't recommend using it.

Comment: thanks for the answer ontrack and definately +1 for the alternate method of handling outside the method definition.  I will consider it an option and benchmark its slowness and viability in future projects.  It is really too bad that they couldn't add type hinting for primitive data types. (int, string, char, etc.)

Comment: On a side not, another option I suppose would be to create a class for each of the scalars as such: class Integer { }; class String { };  etc and use them as objects to type hint against (and some kind of checking and type casting inside.  (note the use of upper case on the first letter so as not to step on reserved words.  Something like that might be a solution.